# What is effect of negotiateServiceCredential=false in WCF

Tags: wcf-security

I have a WCF service with message security with username type. I have added a service level certificate. I set the `negotiateServiceCredential` setting as `false` in service config.

Then I add reference of the service in console application. The console app config file now has the settings including the negotiate tag value as `false`. Client config also has a encoded certificate value in the config file. Now when I run the application and it seems to be fine.

My doubt is what is the effect of setting the `negotiateServiceCredential` to `false` as the application is calling the WCF successfully. I have not set the certificate either in code or config for the console application.